# как вводить числа в питоне с range(n) в одну строку как в C++

Tags: python, c++

Допустим, у нас есть некое число `n`, и я должен вводить числа до этого `n` как в С++

```
int n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>x;
}
```

Как реализовать это в питоне и сохранить в лист?
Нужно вводить числа в одну строку.

```
n=input()
for i in range(n):
    ???
```

```
ввод 
5
1 2 3 4 5
а не так 
5
1 
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
print([ input(f"Введите {i+1}-е число: ") for i in range(int(input("Сколько чисел надо вводить: "))) ])
```

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужно, чтобы я мог вводить числа в одну строку, точнее как в С++ через пробел, или такое невозможно в питоне?

Answer (score 1):

В чистом виде получить одно число до пробела в питоне нельзя. Однако можно легко разделить исходную строку ввода на числа таким образом:

```
input_array = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
или 
input_array = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

То есть вы считываете целую строку с помощью `input()`, с помощью `split()` делите ее по пробелам на отдельные куски, каждый из которых приводите к типу `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`*list()` - распаковывает элементы списка

```
n = input()

result = [i for i in range(int(n))]
print(*result)
```